# Why String theory introduced in cosmological models to study nature of universe?

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory

Why String theory ?  simple cosmological model is not sufficient for study of nature of universe

Comment: This doesn't appear to contain an actual question. Voting to close.

Comment: Also, you seem to give all your questions this same title until you are asked to do otherwise. Questions should ask something more specific than "Why string theory?" and the title should make it clear what is the topic of the question.

Comment: Sorry, you let us no choice but to close the question. I would suggest that you always first try to answer a question yourself and if you cannot do that, outline where in your approach you cannot come any further by giving a sketch of your achievements so far. In this way, people might be able to see what you really want. Greets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple cosmological model has nothing to predict about the fate of collision of particles at high energies, or any other question about short-distance physics, for that matter. To describe the Universe not just in a broad macroscopic sketch, but also in the microscopic details, one needs a quantum theory, and string theory is the only known consistent theory that reconciles particle physics (such as gauge theories with chiral fermions) and general relativity (the latter including cosmological models).

Comment: thanks for understanding . Can u suggest a basic book ( or  some paper from internet)to understand  it.I have read your answers for various string problems...and  satisfactory answers .